# Proving $\arctan(\frac{x\sin{(\pi t)}}{1+x-2x\cos^2({\pi t/2})})=\arctan(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\tan{(\pi t/2)})-\frac\pi2t$

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

From equating the parts of integrands of integrals found in two different manners (each integrand has a common function with a free parameter), I am able to conclude

$$ \arctan\left(\frac{x \, \sin{(\pi t)}}{1+x-2x\cos^2({\pi t/2})} \right) = \arctan\left( \frac{1+x}{1-x} \, \tan{(\pi \, t/2)} \right)-\frac{\pi}{2} t $$

$$ -1<t<1, \quad -1<x<1 $$

I seek a 'simple' proof by which is meant one that only involves trigonometric identities to a typical high-school student.  That is, no complex analysis used, whereas one might be tempted to start a proof using the identity $\arctan(x) = \mathcal{Im}\log(1+ix).$

Comment: I'm tempted to start by trying $\arctan(\frac AB) = \arcsin(\frac A{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}})$, which follows from drawing a right triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \arctan\big(\frac{x \, \sin{(\pi t)}}{1+x-2x\cos^2({\pi t/2})} \big)=\arctan\big(\frac{x \, \sin{(\pi t)}}{1-x\cos(\pi t)} \big)$$

Now multiplying numerator and denominator with $\displaystyle ({1+\tan^2\frac{\pi t}{2}})$, we get

$$\arctan(\frac{2x\tan\frac{\pi t}{2}}{1+\tan^2\frac{\pi t}{2}-x(1-\tan^2\frac{\pi t}{2})})$$

which can be easily written and further separated as

$$\arctan\big(\frac{\frac{1+x}{1-x}\tan\frac{\pi t}{2}-\tan\frac{\pi t}{2}}{1+\frac{1+x}{1-x}\tan^2\frac{\pi t}{2}})=\arctan(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\tan\frac{\pi t}{2})-\arctan(\tan\frac{\pi t}{2})
$$

beacuse

$$\arctan\frac{a-b}{1+ab}=\arctan(a)-\arctan(b)$$

Comment: There are at least 2 typos in this.  In the first line, the x in the denominator has the wrong sign.  Furthermore, the last expression is not given in the problem statement.  Please be a little more careful; I think you have the right idea.

Comment: @skbmoore: The question is a [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854) and really shouldn't have been answered until [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) is added. Mentioning a possible problem is okay, but the tone of "Please be a little more careful" is a bit condescending from someone asking for help. The person answering is donating their time and deserves a bit of gratitude. We all make mistakes from time to time.

Comment: @robjohn The context was stated; the identity arose in an integral evaluation.  I really thought this would be an easy problem with someone knowing a slick trig ID to solve it.  I think the proposed answer is on the correct path and I stated that. I just see a typo in the first line and the last line and there are only 3 lines. Am I supposed to ignore it?  Exactly how would you state an issue with the answer?  I've been called out on typos before, and I fix them, and thank the person answering for a careful read.

Comment: @skbmoore Oops :-), thanks for pointing, fixed everything now.

Comment: As I said, mentioning a possible problem is fine.  I would have said: "There appears to be a sign error in the denominator of the right hand side of the first equation." There is no need to tell them to be more careful.

Comment: @robjohn as already mentioned , the context is there , the identity arose in an integral evaluation and OP seeks a simple trigonometric proof, but yes It should have added something more , if you want I can delete my answer.

Comment: Looking at other cases, stating "I got this by integrating" is not usually accepted as context. I may be wrong, but we will see if this gets closed by the community.

Comment: I have now learned a valuable lesson, considering all the downvotes.  Never ask a simple question, yet ask that the answer be correct.  In the future I will stick to hard questions that no one answers.  This site is maddening, sometimes.

Comment: @skbmoore: I think if you had included the integration that gave the two answers, you might have avoided some or all of the downvotes.

Comment: @robjohn I stripped the problem to its essence.  I asked for a simple proof.  I upvoted and accepted the answer even though it is still incorrect. I don't care anymore.  I don't even know when I'll return to this site, and I've been a regular contributor for years.

Comment: @skbmoore: regarding being maddened by the site; it is annoying that people who try to get their homework done for them here have made it harder for those who have legitimate questions. The requirement for context, as given in the FAQs, is one way that the community tries to discourage questions where little to no thought has been given.